# Changing CSS in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am trying to change the default css but nothing happens, even if I do

bar.setStylePrimaryName("gwt-TabBar");

Here is my CSS, even trying to change the Header does not work H1

Why isnt it changing?

```
    /** Add css rules here for your application. */


/** Example rules used by the template application (remove for your app) */
body {
  color: black;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 8px solid #C3D9FF;
  background-color: #E8EEF7;
  color: #000099;
  margin: 40px 0px 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gwt-TabBar { 

  background-color: #C3D9FF;

}
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarFirst { 
 background-color: #C3D9FF;
    }
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarRest { 
     background-color: #C3D9FF;
    }
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem { 
 background-color: #C3D9FF;
}
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected { 
 background-color: #C3D9FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some ideas: did you import the css into application? You can either do that in your application.gwt.xml or in your index.html.

is the css loaded? you can check this using firebug. check your target folder or war folder to find out the path.

Answer (score 0):

the browser often caches the css; and you have to force its reload.

you can do this by pressing the shift key when you press the "reload" button.

I second checking if the css has changed in firebug as well.